# Can i set outlook to dismiss reminders if I click open and not just dismiss?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When an outlook reminder pops up, and I click open the calendar entry opens (as expected) but the reminder still stays in the background. It's seems more intuitive to me that if I click open the alert should be dismissed also as I clearly have read and actioned the reminder.

Is there a way to reprogram that button to include this response? or a setting somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting because there is no way to distinguish between "Dismiss" and "Snooze". Just because a user has "actioned the reminder" doesn't mean they don't want to be reminded again.